How to share an Excel link so that a copy is opened on OneDrive?
I am a statistics teacher with a class of 24 students.  For the first time this semester, I am trying teach my students to use Excel in Microsoft 365 accessed from a browser. I want to provide my students with data for analysis. I know how to "share" a link to an Excel file by creating a link in OneDrive.

The problem is that the link cannot be writable since the first student who did the analysis would effectively show the problem to everyone.
The link cannot be read-only because Excel won't let the students modify the spread sheet to do the desired analysis.
I do not have access to their file system to put a copy of the file into each of their accounts.
I cannot download the XLSX file and then share that with them because the learning management system (LMS) that mediates the class is converting the file into a PDF rather than allowing the students to open the XLSX file. The reason for this is that the LMS doesn't contain Excel within it, so the LMS doesn't have any ways to open an excel file other than as a PDF.
I think I could download the XLSX file and then email it to every student. This is not a good solution as it requires the students to find the email for any particular assignment, and does not allow me to easily update the data should an issue arise. It would also mean teaching the students to download an attachment, save it on their computer, and then open a file from within Excel.  Again, these are new-to-Excel students.

These students are very new to Excel, etc, so having them "copy and paste" the data to a new blank worksheet is difficult for some to negotiate at the beginning.
My question: Is there a way to share a link to the file so that when students click on the link it opens a copy of the file in a new worksheet so that they do not have to copy it on their own?

Update: I tried the solution proposed below. The menu options that are available in the solution are not available to my students. See below.
Does anyone have any other suggestions? (It looks like I could have them download a copy to their computer and then re-load it in Excel. I don't understand why it seems Microsoft is going out of their way to not allow a local copy.)



I am not aware of any way to have the link automatically create a copy of the Excel sheet for the student. And a quick Google search didn't readily turn up any results.
But they can make a copy of it after opening by going to “File -> Create Copy.”

They can decide to download it, or have it created on their own OneDrive.
An easier, more obvious method is when the document is marked as view only, top right corner of the sheet a button is available for editing a copy. This will save a copy to the student's one drive and open it up for editing.


I tried the menu options suggested when I got to school, and unfortunately, the menus indicated above are not available!  (Why, I could not tell you).  Any other suggestions?

I was logged in, but I note that in the screen shots, it appears to not know who I am.  Let me check this tomorrow at school.  It may be that the issue is that despite being logged in, when they click on the link it is forgetting that.  Perhaps if they sign on after clicking on the link, the options you describe will become available.

I checked this in my classroom.  In a room of 20 students, in approximately 6 instances despite logging in first to Excel, when the students clicked on the link they were not given the option to "Create a Copy" because it did not show them as signed in.  For anyone else who follows the guidance here, the options given in the answer are only available if you are signed in to Excel.
